# Spring-data-reactive-cassandra deleteById have no impact

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

**Java:** 20.0.0

**Springboot:** 3.0.1

**Cassandra:** 4.0

```
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<User, UUID> {    
}
```

### method call

```
@Service
public class UserService {
            
   @Autowired
   UserRepository userRepository;
            
   public Mono<Void> removeIfExistingUser(UserRequest userRequest) {
       String userId = userRequest.getUserId();
       String assetType = userRequest.geAssetType();
       String assetId = userRequest.getAssetId();
     
       Flux<User> userFlux = userRepository.findByUserIdAndAssetTypeAndAssetId(userId, assetType, assetId);
       List<User> userList = userFlux.collectList().block();
    
       if (!userList.isEmpty()) {
         User user = userList.get(0);
         Mono<Void> userMono = userRepository.deleteById(user.getId());
         userMono.subscribe();
       }
       return null;
      }
 }
```

Delete is not working, there is no error nothing, but record is still available in database.

Comment: YOu defined `id` as in `Integer` not a `UUID`.

Comment: @M.Deinum id is UUID only.

Comment: Then why did you declare it as an `Integer` in yuor repository? YOu have `ReactiveCassandraRepository<user, Integer>` Where `Integer` is the type of the primaryt key. If that is UUID then make it `UUID` and ditch the find and delete method you defined as those are provided by the `ReactiveCassandraRepository` already. That being said, you are using reactive coding but here you don't subscribe to the `Mono<Void>` so nothing will be executed.

Comment: Do you add a terminal call ?  `Mono<>` is lazy, it there is not treatment it will not be executed..maybe just block().

Comment: @M.Deinum you were correct, I changed  Integer to UUID, I also subscribed to Mono<Void> and still records are not getting delete.

Comment: Please show the code? The full code, as the whole chain needs to be reactive and/or subscribed to. So if you are doing this in a void method it won't work, your whole chain would need to be reactive. If something is not everything is still lazy and you only defined the blue print of the stream as there is no terminal call. So please show the full code from the start of the delete till the repository. Unrelated, but hurts my eyes, you don't need `@Repository` on the spring data repository.

Comment: In your edited code you still don't `subscribe` to the return mono.

Comment: @M.Deinum removed repository annotation, checking.

Comment: @clunven will try in a couple of minutes

Comment: @M.Deinum getting error `Cannot obtain where clauses for entity ` after removing deleteById.

Comment: `deleteById` returns a `Mono<Void>` not a `Mono<User>`. So I'm not sure what you are currently using. That being said, in theory this should work, unless you are calling this in another reactive stream which you aren't subscribing to then this simply doesn't do anything. Is your id really a UUID? Please show your entity, included the imports and package tstatements!

Comment: @M.Deinum Mono<Void> only, I made mistake while typing here.

Comment: As requested please show the full flow you are using to call this and please add your entity.

Comment: @M.Deinum updating my question with full code.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for having patience  with me, I have updated the post, please let me know, if you need anything else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253820/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-m-deinum).

Comment: How do you call this service? Instead of a `void` method make it `Mono<Void>` and do `return userRepository.deleteById(user.getId());` You are using reactive programming so the whole thing should be reactive, also the code that is actually calling this `delete`. I just needed the code from start to finish for this delete.

Comment: @M.Deinum updating with controller code and service class full method definition too.

Comment: @M.Deinum updated with complete code, controller is doing nothing, just taking request and passing to service class.

Comment: @M.Deinum seems to be working now, with the code currently in the question. would try to optimise it little bit though. Thank you so much.

Comment: @clunven Mono<Void> is fine, if fails returning null, block did not required. thank you so much.

Comment: Why use reactive if you are going to block anyway? YOu should be returning the `Mono` from the service method and in your calling method return the result as well. If that is a controller (whichi you haven't shown) that will automatically subscribe and make it work. You should leave your regular Java programming behind and embrace stream processing else you will keep running into things like this.

Comment: @M.Deinum this was an eye opener, going through some tutorials now, I am a PHP developer worked on few existing springboot app and this one creating from scratch, where everything is new and need to explore, Cassandra, reactive programming, java 20 etc .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to shoehorn declarative programming into reactive programming/stream processing. Which doesn't really work well. Your service should look something like this (from the top of my head so you might need to switch around some `map`/`flatMap`).

```java
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public Mono < Void > removeIfExistingUser(UserRequest userRequest) {
        String userId = userRequest.getUserId();
        String assetType = userRequest.geAssetType();
        String assetId = userRequest.getAssetId();

        Flux < User > users = userRepository.findByUserIdAndAssetTypeAndAssetId(userId, assetType, assetId);
        return users.map( User::getId)
             .flatMap( userRepository::deleteById)
             .defaultIfEmpty(Mono.empty())
             .last()
    }
}
```

This will retrieve the users, convert the user(s) to id and call the delete method. It will return the last `Mono<Void>` or a default empty one. Now if the caller of the `removeIfExistingUser` calls subscribe it will work. If that is a controller from Spring MVC/WebFlux you can just return the `Mono<Void>` and the web classes will automatically subscribe.